# Не получается связать swift и mysql

Tags: ios, swift

Swift выкидывает с ошибкой **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** на строке 82, при попытке отправить `POST` запрос на сервер.

```
           let data = [
                "web_pass" : httpREQ.web_pass,
                "operation" : "UserCreate",
                "login" : login.text!,
                "name" : Name.text!,
                "email" : Email.text!,
                "inst" : Inst.text!,
                "status" : 0,
                "pas_hash" : Pas.text!,
                "role" : 1,
                "avatarURL": ""
                ] as [String : Any]

            AF.request(httpREQ.URL, method: .post, parameters: data, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 500).responseJSON { AFdata in
                do {
                    print(AFdata)
                    
                    guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: AFdata.data!) as? [String: Any] else {
                        print("Error: Cannot convert data to JSON object")
                        return
                    }
                    guard let prettyJsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted) else {
                        print("Error: Cannot convert JSON object to Pretty JSON data")
                        return
                    }
                    guard let prettyPrintedJson = String(data: prettyJsonData, encoding: .utf8) else {
                        print("Error: Could print JSON in String")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    print(prettyPrintedJson)
                } catch {
                    print("Error: Trying to convert JSON data to string")
                    return
                }
            }
```

Вот сам URL  "https://desavir.ru/DesavirWeb/5bee9de5061183c964310d0c329e8d5a.php".
При заходе на нее я получаю ответ от сервера, поэтому, ошибки 500 быть не должно, но она есть. Проблемы в коде или с сервером что-то не так?
Серверные обработчики писал по данному примеру: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468868/how-to-connect-mysql-with-swift

Comment: Проверьте, что все text! имеют значение, ошибка говорит, что вы пытаетесь извлечь значение из nil

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, ошибка вылезает на строке ```guard let jspnObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: AFfata.data! )```. Предполагаю что объект AFdata пустой, на что и указывает ошибка 500, но вот только сервер рабочий как и при переходе по ссылке ответ в виде JSON я получаю. 
Серверные обработчики делал по этому примеру « https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468868/how-to-connect-mysql-with-swift»

Comment: По URL вот такой ответ: {"error":true,"message":"\u0412\u044b \u043d\u0435 \u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0437\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u044b"} Т.е. data в AFdata.data! нет, поэтому краш.

Comment: @Soloviev, все верно, ответ такой, в формате json, а разве ответ должен быть другого формата?

Comment: Формат верный, данных нет, есть только error и сообщение об ошибке. Должно быть что-то вроде {"data": {}} Т.е. сервер не возвращает данные.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, не знаю, стоит отдельный вопрос задавать или нет: Безопасно ли вот так открывать файлы сервера для доступа к ним из приложения? Разумеется я поставил хеш-пароль для операций, ссылку также сделал не совсем формата md5, и делаю банальные проверки, но все же?

Comment: Сервер и должен возвращать json, так что если есть логин/пароль и https, то этого должно быть достаточно, имхо.